# How do I convert a Group KEY from LINQ into an int?

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I am trying to group items for a chart control so that I have the number of items per hour . I am trying to get the 'Hour' . Help ?

```
  Things = (from x in recentLeads
                  let dt = x.LeadCreateDate
                  group x by new { dayofyear = dt.Hour } into g
                  select new Thing
                  {
                      Hour = g.Key,
                      NumberInHour = g.Count()
                  }).ToList();

Cannot implicitly convert type '<anonymous type: int dayofyear>' to 'int'
```

EDIT: What if I want to group by hour but show the entire date ? I no longer have access to the full date do I  ?

Comment: dayofyear = dt.Hour ?

Comment: `group x by dt.Hour into g`

Comment: Why not just `group x by dt.Hour into g`?  No need for an anonymous class.

Comment: `new { dayofyear = dt.Hour}` is an anonymous type that you are not using at all. Just `group x by dt.Hour into g` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either change the group by to

```
group x by dt.Hour into g
```

Or the select to

```
Hour = g.Key.dayofyear
```

In the first case the `Key` of the group will now be the `Hour` in the second you have to access the `dayofyear` property of the anonymous class you created.

Comment: A previous piece of code I used had that anon piece in there and that caused more confusing. . Works thanks